# Why was Happy and Carla affected by Azuma's take over of Tenrou Islands magic?

Tags: fairy-tail

When Azuma took over Tenrou Islands Magic and destroyed the tree he broke the divine protection that is usually granted to those who bear the Fairy Tail Emblem/Guild Mark and stole there magic and energy. So why did Carla and Happy's magic get drained by Azuma even though they did not bear the emblem?

If they do have an emblem could you please show me a picture as I cannot find one with them bearing the Fairy Tail Guild Mark.

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I <s>never</s> can't remember see Carla's guild mark, Happy have it behind his back, Picture below is from Galuna Island arc when Gray met Lyon on Curse Island, they (local villager) ask for Natsu, Gray, Lucy, and Happy mark to prove it if they are Fairy Tail's Mage.

[image]

So if happy has it, it not weird that Carla also has it. But she usually wearing full clothes so maybe it's hidden behind her cloth

Answer (score 3):

They do have the Guild mark as they were also able to see Mavis who said she can only be seen by those who has the emblem.

**The guild mark is on their back.**

Here are the pictures:
[image]

[image]

Im not sure about Happy though, because I only googled it, but it says that its from episode 11 of the anime.

But for Carla, I saw it from chapter 378, shown in Wendy's flashback.

Comment: ah yes, I don't remember this chapter, it's weird that Carla and Pantherlily wearing clothes while Happy is completely naked